# Zeros of a holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a connected complex manifold with dimension $n \geq 1$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Suppose that on a coordinate open set $U$, the function takes infinitely many zero that accumulates. If $n = 1$, this implies that $f = 0$ on the whole $X$.

If $n = 2$, this is not the case as one can consider $\mathbb{C}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $(z, w) \mapsto z$. Now suppose that $n = 2$ and say we have parallel lines in a coordinate open set $U$ that "accumulate" to a line. Then **I think** this necessarily implies that $f = 0$ on the whole $X$.

**Question 1.** Can we say more generally about this phenomenon? If $f$ vanishes on "accumulating" hyperplanes, does it necessarily imply that $f = 0$ on the whole $X$?

*̶*̶Q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶2̶.̶*̶*̶ ̶C̶o̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶$̶n̶ ̶=̶ ̶2̶$̶ ̶(̶o̶r̶ ̶h̶i̶g̶h̶e̶r̶)̶.̶ ̶I̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶o̶r̶d̶i̶n̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶o̶p̶e̶n̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶$̶U̶$̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶$̶Z̶(̶f̶)̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶^̶{̶-̶1̶}̶(̶0̶)̶$̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶n̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶$̶U̶$̶,̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶$̶f̶ ̶=̶ ̶0̶$̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶o̶l̶e̶ ̶$̶X̶$̶?̶ ̶

I will be happy to know about that case $X = \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Notice that for compact $X$, this is a trivial problem.

Comment: Question 2: If you require your coordinate open sets to be non-empty, then yes. The function vanishes on a non-empty open set, and hence by connectedness everywhere. For question 1, it may be that some weird definition of "accumulating hyperplanes" makes it not necessarily imply $f\equiv 0$, but for reasonable definitions I can now think of, the answer is affirmative. In the paragraph before, it depends what you call a "line" (real or complex line?), and maybe in what way they accumulate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did mean non-empty coordinate open sets and complex lines. And for Question 2, I only require $f$ to be vanishing on points that are dense in $U$, not all $U$, so the question is not that trivial (at least to me).

Comment: If the zero set of $f$ is dense in $U$, continuity alone gives you that $f$ vanishes identically on $U$. Then the identity theorem gives you that the set $Z(f) = \left\{x\in X : \bigl(\exists V \in \mathscr{V}(x)\bigr)\bigl(f\lvert_V \equiv 0\bigr)\right\}$ - which is open by definition - is closed, and then the connectedness says that either $Z(f) = \varnothing$ or $Z(f) = X$. Since $U\subset Z(f)$, we must have $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Oh yeah. It really was trivial! Thanks. I will edit the question.

Comment: You should see Range's text for a good discussion of thin sets. One quirk about zero sets is that zeros are not isolated anymore so the analysis of zero sets becomes much more taxing. Furthermore, thin sets *must* have measure zero if your function is to not be identically zero so zero sets are quite small in some sense. That said, I do not think there is an immense amount known about thin sets in general as several variable complex analysis is still quite a young (and extremely demanding) *branch* of mathematics.

Comment: I was leading a reading seminar on several variable complex analysis over the summer and I did a good bit of searching on thin (zero) sets but did not come upon very many broad-sweeping results.

Answer (score 0):

The set $Y=\{f=0\}\subset X$ is analytic, hence it has countable collection of irreducible analytic components. Furthermore, those components form a locally finite familly (this is basic *Complex Analytic Sets theory,* e.g. Gunning-Rossi, Narasimhan...). Now any analytic set $H\subset Y$ of codimension $1$ in $X$ would be an irreducible component of $Y$. Hence any collection of such $H$'s inside $Y$ must form a locally finite family (whose union is closed), and so they cannot acummulate anywhere.

Conversely, if you pick any locally finite family of hyperplanes $H_i$ in $\mathbb C^n$, say, then there is an anaytic function $f:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C$ whith zero-set is the union of the $H_i$'s.